# How can I align the items in my navbar to the center?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

How would you align the items in the navbar? I tried using `text-align: center` but to no avail

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />


<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown" id="one">
    <button class="dropbtn">A
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown" id="two">
    <button class="dropbtn">B
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown" id="three">
    <button class="dropbtn">C
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I horizontally center an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-can-i-horizontally-center-an-element)

Answer (score 2):

Protip: Don't use floats. They're a dated and troublesome technique with very few legitimate modern uses.

Instead, use text alignment, automatic side margins, or flexbox.

See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex; /* <---------------------------------- HERE */
  justify-content: center; /* <------------------------ HERE */
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown" id="one">
    <button class="dropbtn">A
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown" id="two">
    <button class="dropbtn">B
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown" id="three">
    <button class="dropbtn">C
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a div named center
and make it an inline-block

```
.center{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Then cover all your drop downs with it like here bellow

```
  <div class="center">
    <div class="dropdown" id="one">
      <button class="dropbtn">
        A
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" id="two">
      <button class="dropbtn">
        B
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" id="three">
      <button class="dropbtn">
        C
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

then add to your css text align center to .navbar

```
  .navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align:center

  }
```

now it will center the div class .center and your dropdown menu items wil always be centered

there are other ways to do it but this looks like the best if you dont declare the width of your div

Under here is the correct full code snippet

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.center {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="dropdown" id="one">
      <button class="dropbtn">
        A
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" id="two">
      <button class="dropbtn">
        B
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" id="three">
      <button class="dropbtn">
        C
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, the CSS panel should not contain HTML (the style tag). You'd also remove the closing style tag from the HTML panel.